# How to mock axios in React with using axios.create function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, axios, jestjs

I'm working on React project where I'm using axios for http requests. I have a separate file with axios configuration like below:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: " http://localhost:3001",
    params: {
    }
})
```

I'm using this in action thunk creators like below:

```
import streams from "../apis/streams";
export const fetchStreams = () => {
    return async(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<void, State, Action>)  => {
        const response: AxiosResponse<Stream[]> = await streams.get<Stream[]>('/streams');
        dispatch({type: ActionType.FETCH_STREAMS, payload: response.data});
    }
}
```

First I created "src/__mocks__/axios.ts" file like:

```
const mockedAxios: any = jest.createMockFromModule('axios');

mockedAxios.create = jest.fn(() => mockedAxios);

export default mockedAxios;
```

then I wrote test like below:

```
import mockedAxios, {AxiosResponse} from "axios";
import streamsApi from '../apis/streams'
import expectedStreams from "../mocks/expectedStreams";
jest.mock('axios')

describe('fetchStreams action', () => {

    it('Store is updated correctly', async () => {
        const mockedResponse: AxiosResponse = {
            data: expectedStreams,
            status: 200,
            statusText: 'OK',
            headers: {},
            config: {}
        }
        mockedAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
            Promise.resolve(mockedResponse);
        })
        const results = await streamsApi.get('/streams');
        expect(results.data).toBe(mockedResponse.data);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately I've received an error like this:

[image]

Why is that? How can I correctly create facke API response in this case?
I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know what was wrong. I forget to add return before Promise like so:

```
mockedAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
            return Promise.resolve(mockedResponse);
        })
```